# Not Able to convert a string to DateTime object in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am not able to convert a string "2018-08-24 18:23:16,060" into DateTime object.

```
$lastTS = [datetime]::ParseExact($lastTSStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff', $null)
```

I am getting 24.08.2018 18:23:16. But I need the string as DateTime object.

Comment: `$lastTS.GetType().FullName`. What makes you believe you're *not* getting a DateTime object?

Comment: I want to read all the contents from log file between startTime and endTime. I read the log file and convert the string to DateTime object and then I compare..  but I amgetting error as 'String was not recognised as valid DateTime'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] of the code that isn't working for you as well as the full error message you're getting.

Comment: Thaks Ansgar...

Answer (score 0):

The code you put here is working

```
$lastTSStr = "2018-08-24 18:23:16,060"
$lastTS = [datetime]::ParseExact($lastTSStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff', $null)
```

This gives an DateTime object.

If your **$lastTSStr** have more data you must do a regular expression to get only the date from the string and parse it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification